# Print formatting after each component

Tags: c, printf

How can I achieve the following print format:

```
   A    B    C   D  C  E  F
TP1944 LIS  OPO  10:00 10:55
XV1    OPO  LECO 12:00 13:35
```

Where:

- A string can go from 2-6 chars
- B and C strings can go from 3-4 chars

Which means the print must take in count that even if for example the A string only uses 5 chars from the 6 possible the extra 1 space still has to be there.

Currently I am doing this:

```
printf("%6s %4s %4s %02hu:%02hu %02hu:%02hu\n", ...);
```

That results in this:

```
TP1944  LIS  OPO 10:00 10:55
   XV1  OPO LECO 12:00 13:35
```

So I know that it`s possible to format before the actual print output but what about after it? Is it even possible to do this with normal printing in C?

Comment: `%s` defaults to right justification.  Just use  `"%-6s %-4s %-4s ..."` to make it left justify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%s` defaults to right justification. Use `"%-6s %-4s %-4s ..."` to make it left justify. [@Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728596/print-formating-after-each-component/56728634#comment100016994_56728596)